# MEAN Stack - Delay in query and request?

Tags: java, ajax, node.js, mongodb, web

I'm trying to learn Node.js and writing a web app with the MEAN stack.

As I send on an array of strings containing item data (say, `["one", "two", "three"]`) to the server side, I have the following code to iterate through the array, check if a document with the element already exists in MongoDB, then accordingly create new documents in the database.

server side code:

```
// items is an array of strings sent from the client side
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item_name = items[i];            

        // For each item, find an existing one
        Item.findOne({'name': item_name }, function(err, item) {
            // If not already existing, add to database.
            if (!item) {         
                var new_item = new Item();
                new_item.name = item_name;

                new_item.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that `new_item.name`   always equals the last element in the array, i.e. `"three"`

My guess is that the query in the database takes longer than the loop to run, so by the time we're in the callback of `findOne()`, we've already iterated to the end of the array.

Is this true?  If so, what would be a work around for this problem?

I understand that this is potentially be a common question that many may have asked before, but after some time of searching I'm still not able to solve the problem.  Please advise.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but instead of finding and then adding if it doesn't exist. You should be able to do an upsert instead. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: you need to use a wrapper function

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item_name = items[i];            

     (function(name){
        Item.findOne({'name': name }, function(err, item) {
            // If not already existing, add to database.
            if (!item) {         
                var new_item = new Item();
                new_item.name = name;

                new_item.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            }
        });
    })(item_name);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a comment that says to do this. You can create closure (as below) or create a separate function that's outside of the loop. Here's a little blog post about closures http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/09/javascript-closure-explained-using-events

```
// items is an array of strings sent from the client side
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  (function(item_name) {    
    // For each item, find an existing one
    Item.findOne({'name': item_name }, function(err, item) {
      // If not already existing, add to database.
      if (!item) {         
        var new_item = new Item();
        new_item.name = item_name;

        new_item.save(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    });
  })(items[i]);
}
```